# Embedding tables into questions in exam class documents

Tags: tables, exam

I am writing a test in the exam class and having a bit of trouble. I'd like to embed a table into a question but doing so produces the "multiply-defined" warning and breaks the flow of the questions section. Here is my code...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\providecommand\newthought[1]{%
\addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
\noindent\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}
\center Cumulative Review
\begin{flushleft}
\newthought {As you guys know} we are required to give three summative exams which collectively count as \%60 of your grade. I thought it'd be nice to make one of those three tests a cumulative review of that which you have learned thus far. Enjoy!\\
\end{flushleft}

\vspace{5mm}
\makebox[\textwidth]{Name and section:\enspace\hrulefill}\\

\vspace{5mm}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Instructor’s name:\enspace\hrulefill}\\

\vspace{5mm}

\center Record your answers on the bubble sheet provided. 

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{questions}
\question Which of the following is an example of the associative property of addition? \vspace{5mm}
\begin{choices}

\choice $a(b+c)=ac+bc$
\choice $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$
\choice $(ab)c=a(bc)$
\choice $a+b+c=c+b+a$

\end{choices}
\vspace{5mm}
\question Which equation can be used to generate the given table?  

\center
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
\hline
x & y \\ \hline
4 & 25 \\ \hline
7 & 25.75 \\ \hline
16 & 28 \\ \hline
18 & 28.50 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{choices}

\choice $y=.5x+24$
\choice $y=.5x$
\choice $y=.25x+24$
\choice $y=.25x$

\end{choices}
\vspace{5mm}
\question The next question

\end{questions}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

If I remove this...

```
\center
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
\hline
x & y \\ \hline
4 & 25 \\ \hline
7 & 25.75 \\ \hline
16 & 28 \\ \hline
18 & 28.50 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

...the question environment keeps on working nicely but I loose my table.

I am very new to using Latex so its possible I am missing something rather simple. I just don't know yet. Thank you in advance for any help you have to offer.

Comment: Use `\centering` or the `center` environment to center the contents. I am not able to reproduce the problem though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote the test with the article class. I will explore the \centering command and the center environment to see if that resolves the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using \begin{center} and \end{center} has resolved the problem. Thanks again.